# syntax error populating listbox with sql query result

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to populate a listbox with the following code but I get an error saying ListItem could not be found.
Also rathen than creating a new listbox here I want to populate one on my windows forms gui called listbox1 but it says it does not exist in the current context if I change the first line to `ListBox lb = listbox1();`

```
ListBox lb = new ListBox(); 
string connectionString = "your connection string here"; 
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) 
{ 
    con.Open(); 
    string query = "SELECT column FROM myitemstable"; 
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con)) 
    { 
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) 
        { 
            while (reader.Read()) { 
                lb.Items.Add(new ListItem((string)reader["column"])); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: `listbox1.Items.Add(new ListItem((string)reader["column"])); `. no need to declare anything

Comment: What do you mean exactly what do I need to add/remove?

Comment: no worries I have sorted it thanks

Answer (score 1):

when you drag and drop control to UI, Visual studio generate code for it. (Check your designer.cs file)

listbox1 is the object created by the designer, you can directly add items to it.

you can't do below

```
ListBox lb = listbox1();
```

because listbox1 is object.